# call function of class outside of the class in flutter

Tags: flutter

i have a question.
i have this class:

```
class TableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 final String table_number;

  const TableWidget({Key? key, required this.table_number}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TableWidget> createState() => _TableWidget();
}



class _TableWidget extends State<TableWidget> {

  Color? iconcolor = Colors.black;

  void checkstate(){
    print(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++){
      if(lines[j].substring(0, 7) == widget.table_number){
        setState(() {
          iconcolor = Colors.red;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

      children: <Widget>[
        // Some code
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Now, i have multiple copies of the TableWidget class, and i have them in a List , to be precise, 9 of them:

```
List<TableWidget> tables = [
  TableWidget(table_number: "Table 1"),
  TableWidget(table_number: "Table 2"),
  TableWidget(table_number: "Table 3"),
  TableWidget(table_number: "Table 4"),
  TableWidget(table_number: "Table 5"),
  TableWidget(table_number: "Table 6"),
  TableWidget(table_number: "Table 7"),
  TableWidget(table_number: "Table 8"),
  TableWidget(table_number: "Table 9"),
];
```

**How can i call the checkstate() function for each one of the 9 instances of the class, outside of the class, say in main();**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it in the first class TableWidget instead of _TableWidget which is a stateful class. It allows you to access the forEach feature in other classes.

Something like this:

```
class TableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String table_number;

  static Color? iconcolor = Colors.black;
   void checkstate(int i){
    print(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++){
       if(lines[j].substring(0, 7) == widget.table_number){
          iconcolor = Colors.red;
       }
    }
  }

  const TableWidget({Key? key, required this.table_number}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TableWidget> createState() => _TableWidget();
}


class _TableWidget extends State<TableWidget> {




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

      children: <Widget>[
        // Some code
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But then how can i use the iconcolor variable inside the _TableWidget class? Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

well if the List tables is global then you can do a simple for loop.
something like:

```
for(var table in tables){
table.checkstate()}
```

Comment: i tried it but got an error: The method 'checkstate' isn't defined for the type 'TableWidget'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'checkstate'

Comment: The function checkstate() is inside the _TableWidget class, not inside the TableWidget class, thats where i get the headache.